# $\lim_{h\to0}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)|=0$,then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

$f(x)$ is a bounded continuous real function on $\mathbb{R}$.And $f(x)$ satisfies that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)|=0$$
Prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
I have thought of this question for a long time,but I cannot solve it.Any hint will be helpful.Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want me to do that?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3978738/42969

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  I have thought it for a long time,but I hardly have any idea.I need some hints.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks!It's really helpful.