# How to understand the following derivation result

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Known $$F(t)=\iint_{[0,t]^2}f(xy)dxdy$$
So$$F^{\prime}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(tx)dx+\int_{0}^{t}f(ty)dy$$
I try to use the product derivative formula to find the derivative. It's different from what I think. Can you explain it for me, thank you

Comment: As a side note, the formula simplifies further to $$F'(t) = 2\int_0^t f(tx)dx$$ because the name of the integration variable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\psi(y,t):=\int_0^tf(xy)dx$$
Then $$F(t)=\int_0^t\psi(y,t)dy$$
So by the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we have: \begin{align*}
F'(t)&=\psi(t,t)+\int_0^t\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}(y,t)dy\\
&=\psi(t,t)+\int_0^t\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^tf(xy)dx\right)dy\\
&=\int_0^tf(tx)dx+\int_0^tf(ty)dy
\end{align*}
(Of course, I assume that all the derivatives and integral exist)

Comment: Thank you. Can you try to start with univariate functions？

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand what you mean, maybe you could say concretely what you want to prove or calculate?

Comment: I mean, is there any way to get rid of the partial derivative? Or do we have to use the partial derivative,Thank you

Comment: I think most ways to solve this problem will use the partial derivative at some point since if you want to differentiate the whole integral then you will also need to take the derivative of the inner integral (i.e. $\psi$) at some point and since that depends on two variables you would need a partial derivative. Maybe there is some simplification in this special case that could avoid that, but I don't see that at the moment.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. Let me think about it again

Comment: Can I understand that$$F^{\prime}(t)=\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(xy)dx\int_{0}^{t}dy\right)^{\prime}=\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(xy)dx\right)^{\prime}\int_{0}^{t}dy+\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(xy)dy\right)^{\prime}\int_{0}^{t}dx=\int_{0}^{t}f(tx)dx+\int_{0}^{t}f(ty)dy.$$

Comment: In the first equality you can't simply pull the $f(xy)$ out of the $y$-integral since it is not constant with respect to $y$. Otherwise $F'$ seem to depend on $y$ which it doesn't.

Comment: How about this?$$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}dx\int_{0}^{x}f(xy)dy+\int_{0}^{t}dy\int_{0}^{y}f(xy)dx$$So$$F^{\prime}(t)=\left(\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(xy)dy\right)dx\right)^{\prime}+\left(\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{y}f(xy)dx\right)dy\right)^{\prime}=\int_{0}^{t}f(ty)dy+\int_{0}^{t}f(tx)dx$$

Comment: There is still more or less the same problem with the first equality. Also how can you just change the integral limits?

Comment: I divide the integral region into two triangular regions and exchange the order of integration

Comment: Ok, you are right. In that case it should be correct (in your first line the integrals should be inside eachother like you wrote in the second line).

Comment: Thank you.You gave me a lot of guidance